# Dynamic serialization/deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I use Spring MVC and Jackson to drive the API of a application that I work in.  I am faced with the following situation, we need serialize the Person class below in two different ways...

```
@Entity
Order{
    String id;
    String name;
    String address;
    List<Items> items;
}

@Entity
Item{
    String id;
    String description:
}
```

The two situations reposes on the serialization or not of the content of the "items" field in accord with the service that was called.

For example, the service http://localhost/order, results without the "items" field.

```
{
 "id": "1", 
 "name" : "Bill",
 "address" : "any address",
}
```

In the other hands, the second way is http://localhost/order/[id_order]/item/[ids_items], results with the field "items" that was give on the parameter.

```
{
 "id": "1", 
 "name" : "Bil",
 "address" : "any",
 "items" : [{
          "id" : "33",
          "description" : "Item 33"
      }]
}
```

Comment: Why does your REST request on `item` doesn't return an `item` but an `order` ?

Comment: @Michael The requirement specify that the route `http://localhost/order/[id_order]/item/[ids_items]` should return a `order` with a list of `items`. It means that it exists also the route `http://localhost/item/[id_item]`, but it doesn't concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `@JsonView`

You can use [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) to filter fields depending on the context of serialization. It is [supported by Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring).

First define your views:

```java
public class View {         
    interface Default { }  
    interface Detailed extends Default { }   
}
```

Then annotate your fields using the desired view:

```java
@Entity
public class Order {

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private String id;

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private String address;

    @JsonView(View.Detailed.class)
    private List<Items> items;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Finally annotate your controller methods to use a view when serializing the response:

```java
@JsonView(View.Default.class) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrder() {
    ... 
}

@JsonView(View.Detailed.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/order-with-items", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity<SampleResults> getOrderWithItems() {
    ... 
}
```

In order to make it work, you may need to disable the *default view inclusion* in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
```

Comment: Thank you @Cassio,  I will give it a try and get back soon.

Comment: It works like a charm....The difficulty that I found was how to annotate the fields from the parent. e.g the `Order` class extends the `Resource` class that contains some fields like editDate, createDate and Id. That class is share with the class `Item` and a lot of others entities. Annotate all those classes is a lot of work and I need create View's for each one. Do you have a idea how use is this more with efficacy.  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rbi-u-b I understand that your *original* question has been answered hence my answer should be marked as accepted. If you have other questions, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) giving all the relevant details and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: @Rbi-u-b But to address your concerning, you may not need to create a view for each class. You could use generic names such as `Summary` and `Detailed` for your views.

Answer (score 0):

With jackson you can modify the result json string on the fly. For example:

```
    // create a new order
    Order order = new Order("id", "name", "addr");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // create a json string with the order
    JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(order);
    //the content of the node at this moment is:
    //{"id":"id","name":"name","address":"addr"}

    // create an ArrayList with the Items
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("id1", "desc1"));
    items.add(new Item("id2", "desc2"));

    // transform the ArrayList to a json string and add it 
    // the the previous node with the Order
    ((ObjectNode)node).put("items", mapper.valueToTree(items));
    String jsonString = node.toString();
    System.out.println(jsonString);
```

The final output is:

```
{"id":"id","name":"name","address":"addr","items":[{"id":"id1","description":"desc1"},{"id":"id2","description":"desc2"}]}
```

For more information visit the official documentation page: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/

Comment: Thanks, it's the approach that looks more close of the requirement, but it's to put in controller or I can use it abroad, for exemple in some annotation?

Comment: @AmanM You can put into the controller or probably you could use AOP to transform your returned value.

Comment: That's a lot of work. Consider `@JsonView`s as described in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45964293/1426227).

Comment: @cassiomazzochimolin I agree, he should go with your answer.

Comment: Certainly, the annotation @JsonView  is less work and this responds concretely my  needs.